# Compare (equal or not) 2 .png images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, png

I have 2 .png images loaded in memory (they exist as 'bytes' objects) and I need to tell if they are equal or not.
I tried to do a checksum, but it doesn't work, since png image format contains some non-pixel data that makes 2 graphically identical images get different checksums.
I just need to compare these images and tell if they are equal or not, I don't need to find similarities or something like this.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your 2 images as numpy arrays with OpenCv s.t.

```
import cv2
image1 = cv2.imread("image1.png")
image2 = cv2.imread("image2.png")
if (image1 == image2):
   print("same images")
else:
   print("not same images")
```

Comment: To be honest, I was trying to find the answer without the big dependency such as OpenCV, but this is correct to I am marking it